# Grayscale JPEG to YCbCr JPEG

Tags: jpeg, grayscale

How can I convert a grayscale JPEG to a YCbCr JPEG?

I am looking for a possibility without converting the JPEG file to RGB and then back to JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Y is the gray channel. All you would need to do is change the number of components in the SOF marker from 1 to three and add dummy Cb and Cr channels that produce all zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've already tried this but it doesn't work for me. Probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What you could do is create an all black image of the same size. Extract the Cb and Cr components of that and splice them into the image. You may need to incorporate the huffman and quantization tables as well.

Comment: I did this too but it still produces some strange errors. I am using JPEGScope to scan the images. It seems that something needs to be done with the "Scan Data" to incorporate the change. (Only my assumption)

Comment: Try tjDecompressToYUV function from libturbojpeg.